# Why is Smarty used as a template engine?

Tags: php, smarty

There are many question about template engines. Smarty is most popular.
I have seen comparisons [here](http://www.raintpl.com/PHP-Template-Engines-Speed-Test/) and [here](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/35/templating-engines-in-php-follow-up).

Smarty uses memory and not fast.
Why is Smarty used as a template engine? I'm confused about how to choose a template engine.

Comment: Why Smarty may use as template engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is a templating engine in its own right.

The reason to use something like Smarty or Twig usually breaks down to allowing untrusted users to edit the template files, without risking php errors or mischievous behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The "best" product (the one that is the widely used) is not always the one with the best code quality, best by performance, best by memory consuming.

But the best product often is the one which has been developed earlier, which has better marketing, better documentation, better community, etc.

Comment: what about better performance?

Comment: @utopia: it is not always true. If there is less performant tool (but with more features) and highly-performed one (but with poor feature set) - then I probably will choose the first.